# How to avoid 'Gradle build' on each Espresso run

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-espresso

I have started with espresso automation. For every test execution, android studio starts Gradle build which is a time consuming process.

How do I avoid 'Gradle Build' for each espresso run? Can we configure Gradle tasks to avoid Gradle Build? If yes, how?

*Note: I tried changing run/debug configurations but could not succeed.*

Answer (score 1):

After a lot hit and trials, I found it myself. And didn't think, it could be so simple.

Here are the steps

- click 'Edit Configuration' on Android studio.

[image]

- Select a Test case
- Remove 'Gradle-aware Make' from configuration
- Click Apply and OK
- Done

Now when you re-run the same test, it wouldn't build the app. And will automatically start Test Execution.

Problem: It is configuration dependant. Means you have to build at least once any test or class. Then only above solution will work.